# How many different $4$-letter words can be formed from the word $\text{MEDITERRANEAN}$?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**

> How many different four-letter words can be formed (the words need not be meaningful) using the letters from the word '$\text{MEDITERRANEAN}$' such that the first letter is '$\text{R}$' and the last letter is '$\text{E}$'?

**My method**

The four-letter words have to arranged like this: $\text{R _ _ E}$.

Therefore, one has to select 2 more letters from the remaining 11 letters.

I can arrange the remaining letters in the following way:

$\text{M, EE, D, I, T, R, AA, NN}$

Or like this:

$\text{M, D, I, T, R, EE, AA, NN}$

Therefore, two cases arise:

- If the two letters are different, then there are $\displaystyle \binom{8}{2}\cdot 2!=56$ words which can be formed.
- If the two letters are the same, then there are $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}=3$ words which can be formed.

Therefore, $56 + 3 = 59$ different four-letter words can be formed.

My question is this - is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: That seems already really short (just two values added up), why do you need it even shorter?

Comment: It is not true that $\binom 32 \cdot 2! = 3$, but $3$ is indeed the number you should be adding

Comment: You solved it the exact same way that I would have.  The double letter combinations have to be analyzed individually.  If you had (for example) a 17 letter word, with the first and last letter fixed, and you had 86 available letters to choose from, many of them as groups of two or more repeated letters, then **yes** you would want to create *general formulas*.  But even then, you would have to analyze with your **eyes wide open** just to create the formulas.